# Namespace issue in Rails (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some classes in app/services to which I gave a namespace. For example:

```
module MyArea
  class A
  end
end
```

Then, I want to use it in a Rails model. I tried calling it like this:

```
def models_method
  MyArea::A.new
end
```

But Rails will through a `uninitialized constant MyArea::A` error.

For me it doesn't make sense to call class A something like MyAreaA, as I think it's redundant. Isn't that the whole point of namespacing?

What is your suggestion in order to inform of the namespace and at the same time not being redundant?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure MyArea is getting loaded? Have you tried requiring the file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting this error for your folder structure.

You have to add your namespace as follows:

**Step 1.** Create one folder named `report`. In my case `report` is my namespace. Change this name as per your requirement.

**Step 2.** Put your service file inside `report` folder.

```
# app/services/report/meetings.rb

module Report
  class Meetings
    def your_method
      # your codes here...
    end
  end
end

# or you can write like this.

class Report::Meetings
  def your_method
    # your codes here...
  end
end
```

**Step 3:** Now you can call your method anywhere inside your rails app.

```
obj = Report::Meetings.new
obj.your_method
```

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

@borjagvo it's possible your model where the service class `MyArea::A` is being initialized is also namespaced

```
module ModelNamespace
  class ActualModel
    def models_method
      ::MyArea::A.new
    end
  end
end
```

You can fix it by prepending it with `::` which is the *"Constant resolution operator"*